# ABC pdf, use specific proxy server for Gecko

Tags: c#, abcpdf

Is it possible to configure which web proxy server and credentials the Gecko engine uses to convert HTML to PDF in ABC PDF.

I cannot find any option to set this up in the settings.
We are using the engine in a service and would prefer the proxy details be programmatically supplied rather than merely using the proxy that the service user happens to be configured with.

Thanks

Comment: As per my experienced ABC PDF does not provide such option..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Gecko configuration](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/1-engine.htm)
>
> The Gecko engine contains a number of preferences that can be configured. There are a set of .js files in the "XULRunner??_?\defaults\pref" folder that are loaded in alphabetical order when it starts. Each file contains a set of preferences. So by adding your own .js file to this folder, you can add in your own settings.

Comment: Thanks Ross. I appreciate the help, though it's really not what I have in mind. That's really the same as configuring them manually on the machine. I could write code to change the machine registry settings for the proxy too. I think we are actually going to replace abc with something else.

Comment: I will wait and see if anyone else has some ideas, otherwise I will take your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it's not what you wanted, but as a source from the manufacturer, it gives a good idea that it's not possible to configure per instance within code, other than by writing files or registry entries (and possibly removing them after the run).